# Add Com library to Flash CS5.5

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I was watching some tutorial, and there trainer imported com.greensock.TweenLite

I downloaded the greensock pacakge but can't figure out how, where to add this files so that when in AS3.0 i type import com.gre... it pops-up.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a source directory anywhere you'd like to keep your own personal library and other 3rd party libraries.  for example, i put everything in a folder `/Developer` on my mac:

[image]

from within Flash Professional CS5.5, select *Preferences > Category: ActionScript > Language: ActionScript 3.0 Settings...*

[image]

here, under *Source Path*, you will choose the folder on your file system that contains your source files.  when this is done, code completion *should* work with these files.

there are other ways to choose specific source paths for specific projects, but the steps i've outlined above is a global approach that only needs to be done once and will insure that the source files in your chosen directory will be accessible to all projects.

Comment: I did what you wrote, but still in Action Script when typing com.greesock it doesn't pop-up and text doesn't change the color to blue just like flash.display does... any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the folder containing the `com` folder. So if you have TweenLite source in a directory like this:

> C:\Flash\libs\TweenLite\com\greensock

Then you would need to add the following class path to Flash:

> C:\Flash\libs\TweenLite\

Here is how to add a path to your classpaths in Flash: [LiveDocs: Set the classpath for ActionScript 3.0](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/UsingFlash/help.html?content=WS06D23361-54E6-4ac2-9D24-081C181BD2DF.html)

Answer (score 1):

Just place the com folder in the root of your project. Like so:

[image]

Now you can access all classes in the greensock package. Just import them in your document-class:

[image]

Here's an example using tweenlite to animate an object on the stage to alpha 1.